# Bayesian- If I only have prior distribution, is there a way to calculate posterior distribution?

Tags: bayesian, simulation

I have a question about Bayesian inference. In my research, I have only a normal prior distribution with known parameters (mean and std.). I do not have a likelihood function, but I need to calculate a posterior distribution parameters (mean and std.).

Is it possible that I only use the prior as input, and through monte carlo simulation (it is not the MCMC, but only monte carlo simulation that give random generated numbers around my prior known mean and std.).

In this way, is it possible to use the final stimulated random numbers as the posterior parameters? Thank you!

Comment: In a typical Bayesian formulation, one needs a prior distribution and likelihood based on data in order to get a posterior distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by no likelihood? You have no data (and want to find out what your unchanged prior beliefs is) or you cannot write down a likelihood for your data? If the latter can you simulate your data given known parameters?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I have the prior parameters, eg the mean and std. Then i use monte cargo simulation to generate random numbers using prior mean and std as inputs. Finally I have the generated simulation numbers. I am not sure is these generated numbers consider as the posterior distributions? where i can compute the posterior mean and std?

Comment: If you only have the prior, there is nothing to analyze.

Answer (score 2):

*Posterior* distribution, by the definition is

$$
p(\theta|X) \propto p(X|\theta)\;p(\theta)
$$

It is a normalized product between *prior* and *likelihood*.

If you just sample values from prior distribution, then what you have, are samples from prior distribution, nothing more.

I don't know what you mean that the parameters of "prior" are "known". If you mean that you know the parameters for some phenomenon of interest and you want to sample from such distribution, then this is neither a prior, nor posterior. In such case, you are simply assuming that the phenomenon of interest has some distribution and using Monte Carlo to approximate the distribution. Bayes theorem is not involved in here either.

Answer (score 1):

If, given a prior $\pi(\theta)$, like $\pi(\mu,\sigma)\propto\sigma^{-\alpha-2}\exp\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\beta+\gamma\mu^2)\}$ and a generative model $X=H(U,\theta)$ where $U$ has a fixed distribution $F$, e.g., $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, one generates$$\theta\sim\pi(\theta)\qquad u\sim F\qquad x=H(u,\theta)$$the pair $(\theta,x)$ is generated from the prior predictive model. The posterior $\pi(\theta|x)$ constructed from this simulation is given by Bayes' formula, for instance
\begin{align}
\mu|\sigma,x&\sim\mathcal{N}(x/(\gamma+1),\sigma^2/(\gamma+1))\\
\sigma^2|x&\sim\text{Ga}^{-1}((\alpha+1)/2,(\beta+x^2)/2)
\end{align}
but it obviously does not bring more information about the value of $\theta$ that has been used for the simulation, since it is already known. If a simulation repeats generating$(\theta,x)$ from the prior predictive model, the distribution of the $\theta$'s will turn into the prior again.